# How to close any opened dropdown boxes upon clicking another dropdown box?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically what I need is: when I click on Selectbox1, PopupMenu1 shows; simultaneously when clicking on Selectbox2, PopupMenu2 shows, but PopupMenu1 automatically hides - how do I do this with the current code I have? It's impossible to do this with my code since my Javascript does too many things at once - it creates and replaces the original Select box, appends styles to it, and implements an open/close DropdownMenu functionality.

I was only able to achieve what I wanted with this code:

```
$('#sel0').on('click', function() {
    $("#it0.select-hide", this).toggle();
    if ( $( "#it1" ).is( ".select-hide" ) ) {
      $("#it0").show();
    } else {
      $("#it1").hide();
    }
});


$('#sel1').on('click', function() {
    $("#it1.select-hide", this).toggle();
    if ( $( "#it0" ).is( ".select-hide" ) ) {
      $("#it1").show();
    } else {
      $("#it0").hide();
    }
});
```

So I just assigned IDs to the Selectboxes and PopupMenus, and did a back-and-forth show/hide code for each Selectbox and it worked, but only for the first time. This was the result: I click on Selectbox1 leave it open, then click on Selectbox2 and Selectbox1 automatically closes (the result I wanted). But when I go back and reclick Selectbox1, it remains closed and will not open (not good result). Then when I click on Selectbox2, it remains open and will not close (not good result). How do I fix my code so that when I simultaneously click on a second Selectbox, the first Selectbox will automatically close and vise versa?

- Selectbox represents the Class **select-selected**
- PopupMenu represents the Class **select-items**
- **select-hide** is a Class with a property set to **display:none** which makes the PopupMenu hidden.

```js
var x, i, j, selElmnt, a, b, c;
/*look for any elements with the class "custom-select":*/
x = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
  /*for each element, create a new DIV that will act as the selected item:*/
  a = document.createElement("DIV");
  a.className = "select-selected";

  var list = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
  for (var g = 0; g < list.length; g++) {
   list[g].id = "sel" + g;
  }

  var list3 = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
  for (var f = 0; f < list3.length; f++) {
   list3[f].setAttribute('data-drop', 'it' + f);
  }

  a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  x[i].appendChild(a);
  /*for each element, create a new DIV that will contain the option list:*/
  b = document.createElement("DIV");
  b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");

  var list2 = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
  for (var d = 0; d < list2.length; d++) {
   list2[d].id = "it" + d;
  }

  for (j = 1; j < selElmnt.length; j++) {
    /*for each option in the original select element,
    create a new DIV that will act as an option item:*/
    c = document.createElement("DIV");
    c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
    c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        /*when an item is clicked, update the original select box,
        and the selected item:*/
        var y, i, k, s, h;
        s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
        h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
        for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
          if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
            s.selectedIndex = i;
            h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
            y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
            for (k = 0; k < y.length; k++) {
              y[k].removeAttribute("class");
            }
            this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
            break;
          }
        }
        h.click();
    });
    b.appendChild(c);
  }
  x[i].appendChild(b);
  a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      /*when the select box is clicked, close any other select boxes,
      and open/close the current select box:*/
      var body = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
      e.stopPropagation();
      closeAllSelect(this);
      // this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
      this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
      this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active"); //select-items group
    });
}
function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {
  /*a function that will close all select boxes in the document,
  except the current select box:*/
  var x, y, i, arrNo = [];
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
  y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected")[0];
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    if (elmnt == y[i]) {
      arrNo.push(i)
    } else {
      y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
      x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
      // x[i].classList.add("select-arrow-active");
    }
  }
}
/*if the user clicks anywhere outside the select box,
then close all select boxes:*/
document.addEventListener("click", closeAllSelect);
```

```css
/*the container must be positioned relative:*/
.custom-select, .custom-select2 {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
height: 32px;
}
.cscon{
  width: 160px;
}
.csloc{
width: 160px;
top: -27px;
left: 142px;
}
.cslx{
top: -3px;
left: 145px;
}
.cswx, .cshx{
top: -3px;
left: 155px;
}
.custom-select select, .custom-select2 select{
  display: none; /*hide original SELECT element:*/
}
.select-selected, .select-selected2{
  background-color: white;
/*  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 6px 8px 5px 8px;*/
}
/*style the arrow inside the select element:*/
.select-selected:after, .select-selected2:after{
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 14px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-color: black transparent transparent transparent; 
}

/*point the arrow upwards when the select box is open (active):*/
.select-selected.select-arrow-active:after, .select-selected2.select-arrow-active2:after{
  border-color: transparent transparent black transparent;
  top: 7px;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
/*style the items (options), including the selected item:*/
.select-items div, .select-selected, .select-items2 div, .select-selected2{
  color: black;
  padding: 6px 8px 5px 8px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  /*background-color: white;*/
}
/*style items (options):*/
.select-items, .select-items2{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  top: 100%;
  left: -1px;
  z-index: 99;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 100%;
}
.select-items2 {
width: 100%;
}
.cswt {
  top: -3px;
  left: 160px;
}
#smsel{
/*width: 60px;*/
}
/*hide the items when the select box is closed:*/
.select-hide, .select-hide2 {
  display: none;
  transition:all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
.select-items div:hover, .same-as-selected, .select-items2 div:hover, .same-as-selected2{
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition:all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="cl1" class="custom-select cscon">
      <select id="sl0" class="sel2 lngsel" name="cond" required="required">
        <option value="brandnew">Brand New</option>
        <option value="likenew">Like New</option>
      </select>
</div>

<div id="cl1" class="custom-select cscon">
      <select id="sl1" class="sel2 lngsel" name="cond" required="required">
        <option value="brandnew">Brand New</option>
        <option value="likenew">Like New</option>
      </select>
</div>
```